# Use datetime data from SQL query to populate "input type=time" field

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I'm trying to get an SQL query with PHP to populate various fields in a form so they can be edited by a site administrator. Those two fields are date and time.

I'm using the two input types 'date' and 'time'. The date field is populating perfectly. The time field is coming up blank. The data for both is coming from the same SQL query. I'd like them both to display within the intended format for each field. (I'm using Chrome for this as I know the field types aren't supported by all browsers).

```
//Queries
        $pull_game = "select datetime, city, opponents.opponent_id, game_type, tourn_name, time, home_score, vis_score, day_of_week, month, day, year, parks.park_id, park, win, loss, tie, result from games, opponents, parks, tournaments where opponents.opponent_id = games.opponent_id and parks.park_id = games.park_id and tournaments.tourn_id = games.tourn_id and game_id= ".$_POST['game_id'] . ";";
        $game_stats = mysqli_query($con,$pull_game) or die("ERROR: $pull_game. ".mysqli_error());
        $game = mysqli_fetch_array($game_stats);

//Display data
        <input type='date' name='date' value=<?= $game['datetime']?>>
        <input type='time' name='time' value=<?= $game['datetime']?>>
```

I've tried eliminating the date field to see if the time field would work, but it still came up blank. I've had no luck researching this - most of the content I find is for updating the DB with datetime data. I'm looking for the opposite (sort of).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you're stuffing a full-blown date/time field in there? `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` is not a valid "time" value, so don't be surprised if the field comes up blank.

Comment: Also missing quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Queries
        $pull_game = "select date(datetime) as d, time(datetime) as t, city, ..."

//Display data
        <input type='date' name='date' value=<?= $game['d']?>>
        <input type='time' name='time' value=<?= $game['t']?>>
```

should do the trick. Valid date and time formats for HTML5 inputs are described in https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#dates-and-times - essentially it's YYYY-MM-DD for "date", and HH:MM:SS for "time" inputs. Conveniently, this is exactly the output MySQLs date() and time() functions yield (cp. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

Comment: Thanks vigo, this worked out perfectly. Really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

you could use a substr function to escape the chracters from the date and add only the time or you can also try using the ***strtotime*** function too, to convert the data type you are getting from the query and put it into the fields you need

```
$date2=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
```

[check the strtotime function here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_strtotime.asp)

***Also I don't think there is a input type="time" so, check the existsent input types***

Comment: Thanks for the alternate approach, Marcela. I appreciate the help. The input type is a valid one - http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp